# Can Rasa NLU share the same spacy model among multiple models

Tags: spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am using Rasa NLU. I have 3 models trained using the same pipeline with different training datasets. The pipeline uses Spacy for tokenization and to build the WordVec.

When I load all of those 3 models to memory, Exactly how many times, Rasa loads Spacy en_core_web_lg model to the memory? Can we share the same Spacy model between multiple trained NLU models?

Comment: What is the Rasa version you used?

Comment: Using the version 2.2

Answer (score 1):

The Spacy model will be *loaded into memory* each time you train a model using it. It will however only be *downloaded* once, in which sense the same model is used for all NLU models trained in the same environment.